# how to add closing and opening function bet per match in soldity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

source code:https://github.com/laronlineworld/bettingMatch/blob/main/bettingMatch.sol

How to open and close bet per match

```
function bet(uint16 _matchSelected, uint16 _resultSelected) public payable {

  //Check if the player already exist
//   require(!checkIfPlayerExists(msg.sender));

  //Check if the value sended by the player is higher than the min value
  require(msg.value >= minimumBet);
  
  //Set the player informations : amount of the bet, match and result selected
  playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].matchSelected = _matchSelected;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].resultSelected = _resultSelected;
  
  //Add the address of the player to the players array
  players.push(msg.sender);

  //Finally increment the stakes of the team selected with the player bet
  if ( _resultSelected == 1){
      totalBetHome[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
  else if( _resultSelected == 2){
      totalBetAway[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
  else{
      totalBetDraw[_matchSelected] += msg.value;
  }
```

}

This is the code for opening the betting

```
 /* Function to enable betting */
function beginVotingPeriod()  public onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    bettingActive = true;
    return true;
}
```

how about opening the bet per match?

also closing the bet per match

```
/* Function to close voting and handle payout. Can only be called by the owner. */
function closeVoting() public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    // Close the betting period
    bettingActive = false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to control voting per match, you'll need to use a mapping as follows:

```
mapping(uint16 => bool) matchBettingActive;
...
function beginVotingPeriodForMatch(uint16 _match)  public onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    matchBettingActive[_match] = true;
    return true;
}
function closeVotingForMatch(uint16 _match) public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
    // Close the betting period
    matchBettingActive[_match] = false;
    return true;
}
```

Update:
Also, you want to make sure the betting is active at the beginning of your `bet(...)` function call as follows:

```
function bet(uint16 _matchSelected, uint16 _resultSelected) public payable {
  require(matchBettingActive[_matchSelected], "Betting: match voting is disabled");

  //Check if the player already exist
//   require(!checkIfPlayerExists(msg.sender));

  //Check if the value sended by the player is higher than the min value
  require(msg.value >= minimumBet);
  ...
}
```

Comment: How about checking the status of match_id before betting? Is it like this ```require(matchBettingActive)```?

Comment: @LloydRamos definitely, you want to make sure betting is active before you make your bet. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help sir, realy appreciate, I have One last question about this betting? I can't bet on other match_id because everytime I bet -->  //Set the player informations : amount of the bet, match and result selected
  playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].matchSelected = _matchSelected;
  playerInfo[msg.sender].resultSelected = _resultSelected; this works

Comment: Is there a way that one address can bet on diffrent matches without changing the playersInfo?

Comment: @LloydRamos you would need to change the data structure of playerInfo so that instead of one value for `playerInfo[msg.sender].matchSelected`, it would have a mapping of values. Also, you need to include resultSelected in the mapping so that the relation with matchSelected remains traceable. But things would get exponentially more complex with that.

Comment: Oh see, Thank you, I'll try to figure it out, I'm trying to test and perfectly complete this bet. Hope I finish this.

Comment: If you can help me, with this :(

Comment: can you help to construct the structure of betting on multiple matches so that I have guide to follow, I don't know where to start. Thank you.